# ADO called from C++ much slower in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c++, asp-classic, ado, windows-server-2008-r2

We have some old C++ code which is being called from Classic ASP. It runs on Windows 2000 and is invoked using CreateObject via COM from the ASP. The code uses an ADO recordset (server side) which is passed to it from ASP and loops through the records, producing an XML file.

We have moved the C++ DLL onto a Windows 2008 server and it is a lot slower. Using Wireshark we can see this is because every time it moves to a a new record it restablishes the connection.

The old server used ADO 2.7 the new server uses ADO 6, but these are functionally equivalent and its just a new label for the version as I understand it.

Here is the main body of the code. It doesn't compile because I have removed bits to try and simplify the structure.

```
{
STDMETHODIMP Crender::generatexmldoc(LPDISPATCH adorecordset)

    _Recordset rs;
    rs.AttachDispatch(adorecordset);
    CStringArray* fieldnames = new CStringArray();
    int recno = 0;
    LPDISPATCH fs = rs.GetFields();
    while ( rs.GetState() == 1 && ! rs.GetEof() && recno++ != maxrecords) {
      _generatexmlelement(fs , arecordname, TRUE, fieldnames);
      rs.MoveNext();
    }
    fs->Release();
    rs.DetachDispatch();
    fieldnames->RemoveAll();
    delete fieldnames;
}

void Crender::_generatexmlelement(LPDISPATCH adofields, LPCSTR elementname, BOOL closeelement, CStringArray* fieldnames)
{
  USES_CONVERSION;

  if (fieldnames->GetSize() == 0) {
    for (index.uiVal = 0; index.uiVal < total; index.uiVal++) {
      LPDISPATCH dItem = fs.GetItem(index);
      fd.AttachDispatch(dItem);
      CString name = fd.GetName();
      fieldnames->Add(name);
      fd.DetachDispatch();
      dItem->Release();
    }
  }

  writeoutfile(CString("<") + elementname);
  for (index.uiVal = 0; index.uiVal < total; index.uiVal++) {
    LPDISPATCH dItem = fs.GetItem(index);
    fd.AttachDispatch(dItem);
    value.Attach(fd.GetValue());
    // code removed - data comes from value
    writeoutfile(data, data.GetLength());
    }

    value.Clear();
    value.Detach();
    fd.DetachDispatch();
    dItem->Release();
  }
}
```

What in here could be causing the round trips to re-establish the connection?

Comment: Congrats for finding a situation where [tag:c++] and [tag:asp-classic] are *not* mutually exclusive. :D